# RoR collection_select does not work on array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
  - @variants[:options].each do |o|
    = f.field_container :type do
      = f.label :type, "TYPE"
      = collection_select(o[:type_id], @types, :id, :name)
```

Hello! I have been trying to do this but I get an error `undefined method map for :id:Symbol`

```
@types = Type.all
```

and `@variant[:options]` looks like this

```
[{type_id: 1, type_name: "Color"},{type_id: 2, name: "Shade"}]
```

so the goal of my select is that, I would like to change the `type_id` inside the hash. any help?

UPDATE: so i tried this and it works but there is no selected value on the collection select.

```
= collection_select(o, o[:type_id], @types, :id, :name)
```

Comment: What version of rails are you using? Typically I just use `f.select :column_name, options, {}, class: "something"`. Options in this case would probably be `@variant.map{ |v| [v[:type_name],v[:type_id]]}`. That should work for Rails 4+.

Comment: @Nuclearman im using rails 4.2, but my problem is not with the options but with the object. since I am not using an actual model, i'm just using a hash :(

Comment: Yea, the above should work. I'm not sure collection select is supposed to use a hash as you can't call named methods on a regular hash (ie: `option.type_id`). The above code should work for you. `options` is just an array of arrays in the format `[[title,value]]`. I find it generally easier to work with as you can use it for pretty much anything via `map` or `pluck`. Though I see it's actually `@variant[:options].map{ ... }` instead. Missed the `[:options]` the first time around. The map just builds an array of arrays using the type name and the type_id as the first and last value.